# Ubuntu volume lower than in Windows

Tags: sound

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 on my Dell XPS 9370, I have noticed that the volume in Windows is much more than in Ubuntu. I have checked alsamixer and both master and PCM are set to 100%.

I know I can increase the volume beyond 100% from the settings but thats really irritating and I want 100% to be the real 100%.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want the volume slider to be labelled differently?

Comment: I just want the volume to be max at 100% without any over amplification

Answer (score 0):

That would be caused by pulse audio and the drivers. Windows Monopolized the marked so hardware vendors pay majority of their time focusing on the windows drivers and very few if any give Linux the time of day.

You can modify the Pulse audio gain and response as well as recompiling your Audio drivers, but I would advise against it in your situation.